# satisfies the requirement PyDispatcher-2.0.5 (from versions: none)

Tags: python, pip

Python `3.9.5` Here I go:

```
deactivate
rm -rf venv/
python -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
python -V
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install wheel
```

fine.

look at the development.txt:

```
mariadb==1.0.5
python-binance==1.0.10
python-decouple==3.3
PyMySQL==0.10.1
mplfinance==0.12.7a4
newtulipy==0.4.6
autobahn==21.3.1
PyQt6==6.1.1
pyqtgraph==0.12.1
PyOpenGL==3.1.5
PyDispatcher-2.0.5
shortuuid==1.0.1
```

try this: development.txt (has is PyDispatcher==2.0.5).
Try this for your self:

```
python -m pip install -r requirements/development.txt
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyDispatcher-2.0.5 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyDispatcher-2.0.5
```

Why?

But on his own:

```
pip install PyDispatcher
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: PyDispatcher in /home/jonsl/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.0.5)
```

Is fine.

Why?

Thank you people.

Comment: so no one else know either.

Comment: How did you generate development.txt? There is a typo in this file. `PyDispatcher-2.0.5` should be `PyDispatcher==2.0.5`. This is the reason your pip install from development.txt is throwing that error.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that:
`pyqtgraph==0.12.1`

needs
`pyqtgraph==0.12.2`
instead with:
`PyQt6==6.1.1`

Also, never use `from ... import ...` unless you need.